# Maven downloads all dependencies again because they were "cached from a remote repository ID that is unavailable in current build context"

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-3, maven-dependency, maven-repository

I have a multi-staged Docker build.

In step one, I download and cache all dependencies (I use the Maven goal `package` for this). This is Docker layer is the base for all future build steps.

In step two, I build the project.

However, in step two, all dependencies get downloaded again. I made sure by using [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) that the dependencies already exist in the Maven repository before and that the correct Maven repository is used.

When I run Maven in debugging mode by passing `-X`, I get this warning before each dependency is downloaded again:

> Artifact XYZ is present in the local repository, but cached from a
> remote repository ID that is unavailable in current build context,
> verifying that is downloadable from XYZ

[Here is the Maven source code where it is printed.](https://github.com/apache/maven-resolver/blob/master/maven-resolver-impl/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/internal/impl/DefaultArtifactResolver.java#L397)

How can I solve this warning? How to keep Maven from downloading the dependencies again?

Comment: Please show your docker file ... how you call Maven etc. much more information are needed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I thought [`dependency:resolve`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-mojo.html#dependency-resolve) also downloads all dependencies. But that's not what it does.